# Inherit all functions from user-defined iterator in reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, inheritance, iterator, user-defined, reverse-iterator

I am writing a JSON class for C++11, see http://github.com/nlohmann/json. My central data structure is a class wrapping the JSON value types (null, array, object, string, bool, number) in a union and offering it in via a nice C++ interface. As arrays (implemented via `std::vector`) and objects (`std::map`) come with their own iterators, I implemented a "wrapper" iterator which delegates calls to `operator++` or `operator->` to the respective member variables. Furthermore, I implemented two additional functions `std::string key()` to access keys of a JSON object and `reference value()` as an alias to `operator*()`.

So far, so good (see https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/master/src/json.hpp for the complete source code)...

Then I wanted to implement `reverse_iterator` and `const_reverse_iterator`. And here the problems begin.

- If I realize them via `using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;` and `using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;`, everything is fine, but the functions `key()` and `value()` are not available with `reverse_iterator` or `const_reverse_iterator` objects.
- If I implement my own class `reverse_iterator` like `class reverse_iterator : public std::reverse_iterator<typename basic_json::iterator>`, I need to implement the whole class again. It is not sufficient to give an implementation for `key()` and `value()`, but also for `operator++()` and all the other stuff which I hope to have gotten for free using the `std::reverse_iterator` adaptor.

I spent quite some time searching for answers, but all references I found either scratching the surface of incomplete toy examples or come to the conclusion that iterators are hard work and one should move to Boost...

So here are my questions:

1. How can I create a `reverse_iterator` from my customized class `iterator` so that it inherits as much functions as possible?
2. If inheriting behavior beyond the standard stuff does not work automatically, how can I write a `reverse_iterator` without repeating myself completely?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I did not receive an answer, so here is what I did. Maybe an ugly solution provokes someone to post something nicer :-)

## Background

So the first thing I learned is that `std::reverse_iterator` does nothing more than to encapsulate a "normal" iterator (called `current`, accessible via `base()`) and to establish the relationship of the reverse iterator being "one element more to the left" than the "normal" iterator.

[image: relationship between iterators and reverse iterators]

(image from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator))

## Generic solution

As long as the "normal" iterator has the standard interface and does not use any additional functions, the lines

```
using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;
```

are sufficient to automagically convert your own iterator class into a reverse iterator.

And with the member functions

```
reverse_iterator rbegin() { return reverse_iterator(end()); }
reverse_iterator rend() { return reverse_iterator(begin()); }
const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const { return const_reverse_iterator(cend()); }
const_reverse_iterator crend() const { return const_reverse_iterator(cbegin()); }
```

reverse iteration is possible, for instance code like

```
for (my_container::reverse_iterator rit = c.rbegin(); rit != c.rend(); ++it)
{
   // rit will iterator container c in reverse order
}
```

works.

## Adding more functionality to iterators

As I wrote in the question, I extended the `iterator` class with two additional members, `key()` and `value()`. The former allows quick access to the key of a JSON object during iteration. The latter is an alias to write `it.value()` rather than `*it`. Unfortunately, the above approach does not inherit these function to `reverse_iterator`.

To enrich the user-defined reverse iterators, we need to inherit from `std::reverse_iterator<iterator>` and delegate calls to the base iterator. Unfortunately, I found no other approach than to do this manually. For the mentioned functions, this looks as follows:

```
class reverse_iterator : public std::reverse_iterator<iterator>
{
  ...

  std::string key() const
  {
      auto it = --this->base();
      return it.key();
  }

  reference value() const
  {
      auto it = --this->base();
      return it.operator * ();
  }  
}
```

The most tricky part is that you need to implement the "off-by-one" relationship manually:

1. Retrieve the base iterator via `base()`.
2. Decrement it to point to the "right" (left, actually...) element.
3. Call the desired function.

And with that, we're nearly done. Nearly, because of the `...` in the code above. What is left to do is to delegate all other calls to functions like `operator++` to the base class. I found now way to let someone else to this boring delegation.

So the class contains code like

```
using base_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;

reverse_iterator operator++(int)
{
    return base_iterator::operator++(1);
}

reverse_iterator& operator++()
{
    base_iterator::operator++();
    return *this;
}
```

(Note the definition of `base_iterator`.)

That's it. We now have user-defined reverse iterators which allow us to code

```
for (my_container::reverse_iterator rit = c.rbegin(); rit != c.rend(); ++it)
{
   std::cout << rit.key() << '\n';
}
```

## Cleaning up

In a discussion on Github, [gregmarr](https://github.com/gregmarr) proposed to combine the `reverse_iterator` and the `const_reverse_iterator` classes into a single template class like

```
template<typename Base>
class json_reverse_iterator : public std::reverse_iterator<Base>
{
  public:
    /// shortcut to the reverse iterator adaptor
    using base_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<Base>;
    /// the reference type for the pointed-to element
    using reference = typename Base::reference;

    /// create reverse iterator from iterator
    json_reverse_iterator(const typename base_iterator::iterator_type& it)
        : base_iterator(it) {}

    /// create reverse iterator from base class
    json_reverse_iterator(const base_iterator& it) : base_iterator(it) {}

...
}
```

This allows to write

```
using reverse_iterator = json_reverse_iterator<iterator>;
using const_reverse_iterator = json_reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;
```

and to be happy.

## Full example

See [here](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/300fba63888d4c39053006f466bfd24937cac972/src/json.hpp#L5516) for the complete code.

I'd still like to see a solution that avoids repeating most functionality, but this one is good enough for me. And as I haven't found anything better in quite a while, I decided to share it.